# jQuery UI Resizable - Synchronous with grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have two resizable elements and I need them to resize Synchronously maintaining the grid. It seems that these two option do not work together. Any ideas?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CbYtT/2/
(Try resizing horizontally)

```
$(function() {

    $( "#this" ).resizable({
        alsoResize: "#that", 
        grid: 100

    });

    $( "#that" ).resizable({
        alsoResize: "#this", 
        grid: 100
    });

});
```

Comment: can you please post your html/css also?

Comment: Sure. http://jsfiddle.net/CbYtT/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not pretty, but it works.

```
    $( "#this" ).resizable({
        handles: "e",
        resize: function(event, ui) {
            $( "#that" ).width($(this).width());
            $( "#that" ).height($(this).height());
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $( "#that" ).width($(this).width());
            $( "#that" ).height($(this).height());
        },
        grid: 100
    });

    $( "#that" ).resizable({
        handles: "e",
        resize: function(event, ui) {
            $( "#this" ).width($(this).width());
            $( "#this" ).height($(this).height());
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $( "#this" ).width($(this).width());
            $( "#this" ).height($(this).height());
        },
        grid: 100
    });
```

The working version of your JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/CbYtT/3/

Comment: So, in conclusion the "alsoResize" option in jQuery UI does not respect the grid... Your answer works. I've removed the "stop" since it is not necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/CbYtT/4/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can get really ugly if you have say 10 or more elements that you need to resize.  Instead lets point the resize to the class shared by all the elements you want to resize.  You can resize like this from any of the elements.

```
  $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
    handles: "e",
    grid: 100,
    resize: function(event, ui) {
      $( ".resizable" ).width($(this).width());
    }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CbYtT/240/